# Получение списка сетевых интерфейсов

Tags: java, сеть

Что есть по этой теме?

Comment: нашел jNetPcap ( оболочка для pcap) на сайте у него сказано что только win/linux, а мне надо под mac os

Comment: jPcap сейчас попытался заюзать - не выходит..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy-paste из [Java туториалов](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ListNets 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
            displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
    }

    static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
        out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
        out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
        for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {
            out.printf("InetAddress: %s\n", inetAddress);
        }
        out.printf("\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: cпасибо  -  то что надо вроде)